# VSFTPD- memory attacks

Tags: memory

How are memory attacks prevented via the VSFTPD server? The platform I am using is Ubuntu.

Please I am not currently having a problem I am just requesting knowledge concerning the subject stated above. Any explanations or links concerning memory attacks on VSFTPD servers would much be appreciated.
Thank you,
B.C.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking.  Is there something special about VSFTPD and memory attacks?

Comment: You're asking about a specific exploit for a specific program?